# Не работает условие с указателем

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <windows.h>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    char *array[][2] = {
        "Домен", "Допустимое потенциальное, ограниченное подмножество значений данного типа.",
        "Хостинг", "Услуга по предоставлению вычислительных мощностей для физического размещения информации на сервере, постоянно находящемся в сети (обычно Интернет).",
        "Сервер", "Аппаратное обеспечение, выделенное и/или специализированное для выполнения на нем сервисного программного обеспечения (в том числе серверов тех или иных задач).",
        "Сайт", "Совокупность электронных документов (файлов) частного лица или организации в компьютерной сети, объединённых под одним адресом (доменным именем или IP-адресом).",
        "", ""
    }, word[20];
    int i;
    cout << "Введите искомое слово: ";
    cin >> word;
    for (i=0;*array[i][0];i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(array[i][0], word))
        {
            cout << word << " - это " << array[i][1] << "\n";
            break;
        }
        if (!*array[i][0])
        {
            cout << "Ничего не найдено\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

26-29 строчки не работают. Почему? http://smotr.im/aLOa

Comment: Это точно на С++ написано? Это какая то дикая смесь С, С++ и неведомого языка (например точка с запятой в конце include).

Comment: Да, тоже интересно стало, зачем ";" после библиотек

Comment: Это так важно?

Comment: для красоты, всё равно ни на что не влияет!

Comment: Может и не важно, и не на что не влияет, но обычно так не пишут + лишний вывод от компилятора при построении проекта в виде предупреждений. Например, в VC++ это выглядит, как warning C4067.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну если оставить в стороне рассуждение о качестве кода, то по сути вот почему не работает:
условие в for 
for (i=0;*array[i][0];i++) 
и условие в if-e 
if (!*array[i][0])
противоположные, но поскольку просчет условия for-а выполняется раньше, то цикл никогда не дойдет до этой итерации.

Минимальное переписывание кода, которое даст работающий вариант - вынести второй if из цикла за него.

Answer (score 0):

1. для `strcmp` подрубаем `<cstring>`  (но вроде бы он уже подрублен в windows)
2. какое условие неработает ? (их там 2 и оба работают неправильно)
3. [читаем внимательно как работает strcmp](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/sprd/strcat_strdup.php)
4. вместо **`if (!*array[i][0])`** ставим **`else`**
5. а лучше использовать переменную в которую записываем нашлась ли word в array и проверку делаем после выхода из for (тоесть выносим второй if)

Comment: А вы учитываете условие в цикле? В таком случае их 3. И какие два из них тогда не работают? Если вместо if (!*array[i][0]) поставить else, то в данном коде, вывод "Ничего не найдено\n"; будет срабатывать пока ничего не найдётся. Оно нужно автору?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat и почему первое условие работает неверно?

Comment: @brightside90 

 1. я имел ввиду if() ...
 2. читаем внимательно пункт 5 (так как это, существенная переделка программы, вынес в отдельный пункт)

@Андрей Шаповалов 
я непросто так скинул ссылку. `strcmp` сравнивает даже не символы а их интовое представление при этом `strcmp` не проверяет размер литералов, то есть для `strcmp` `("num" == "numbers")` и при этом  `("num" != " num")` а так же `("num" != "Num")` потому как коды символов разные...

а это ведёт к ошибкам поиска

Comment: Да, 5-й пункт я не стал затрагивать, т. к. сам так же сделал бы, но там надо не просто выносить второй if, а проверять ту самую новую переменную. Ну, мы друг друга поняли.

Comment: @brightside90 а что можно вынести if и при этом не создавать ещё одну переменную?? :)))

Answer (score 0):

[[@Андрей Шаповалов](/users/10877/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/10877/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), IMHO у Вас проблемы с вводом русских букв в винде. Наверняка у Вас все настроено так, что текст вводится (несмотря на SetConsoleCP(1251)) **в cp866**.

Программа-то (не смотрите на предыдущие ответы) в Ubuntu **работает** (даже в кодировке utf-8).

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ strarr.cpp 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Введите искомое слово: Сайт
Сайт - это Совокупность электронных документов (файлов) частного лица или организации в компьютерной сети, объединённых под одним адресом (доменным именем или IP-адресом).
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Более точно, работает после выбрасывания

```
#include <windows.h>;
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);
```

и

```
system("pause");  // ну, это практически не влияет
```

и добавления

```
#include <string.h>
```

а также приведения типа к (char *) перед всеми строковыми константами. (по сути тоже не влияет, но просто я не люблю warnings).

Мой абсолютно частный совет: переходите на обучение программированию в линукс (или любой *nix), научитесь (и если понадобится) напишите и в винде. Если уж совсем никак, то *ручками* делайте перекодировку ввода-вывода с консолью.

**UPDATE**

Вынесите

```
if (!*array[i][0])
{
    cout << "Ничего не найдено\n";
}
```

из цикла (как в ответе [@van](/users/4648/van) Pizhenko), тогда все случаи отрабатывают.

Comment: @avp да нет, поиск работает. Строки сравниваются.

Comment: Ок! Вынесите 

    if (!*array[i][0])
    {
        cout << "Ничего не найдено\n";
    }

из цикла (как в ответе @van Pizhenko) и все заработает. Думал просто strcmp() у Вас не срабатывает, потом глянул повнимательней.

Кстати, зря Вы в вопросе пишете просто **номера** строк, которые не работают. Лучше их как-то более явно указывать. (В самом деле, не считать же их?)

Comment: @avp не обратил внимания, что здесь строки не нумеруются.